# Should I use GTM container id or measurement id in react using ga4?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I need to gather analytics on my website with google analytics 4. Using enhanced measurement I catch all button clicks by creating triggers with "*Click element matches CSS selector [data-analytics="action-name"]*" and using **React-ga4** library I send some custom events such as errors events or some auth events.

The problem in my case that if I use "*GTM-XXXXXX*"(id of the container in Google Tag Manager) when initializing ga4 like this:

```
ReactGA.initialize("your GA measurement id");
```

then I gather all button clicks, but if I initialize with "*G-XXXXXXX*"(Measurement ID from GA4 data stream) then I gather all custom events sent with **react-ga4**, but not button clicks(they don't even appear when I try to debug). I also have GA4 configuration tag, with measurement id linked to it.
I tried to search for the solution or any documentation on how to connect them or what id I should initialize, but couldn't find anything. I'm thinking about initializing both, but not sure yet. What id should I initialize? Am I doing it wrong? Is it possible to track both custom events sent from the code and GTM events?

Comment: you should decide what you wanna use, GTM or GTAG? if you wanna use GTM then you should define Google Tag, and GA Event Tag, then the related triggers and for custom dimesions you need to create variables etc. then in the head tag you paste the GTM code provided by the tag manager, plus it is better to add the body tag related code as well. on the other hand, in the front-end part you should call your GA function sending desired data.

Comment: @ShilaMosammami if you have any example of adding custom event to GTM, so it will appear after I send it from my code, then could you please share it?